# Is it safe to use just a HashMap in multiThreaded env to read from it?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
          Map<Long, List<Long>> relevantModules = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            Map<Long, List<Long>> notRelevantModules = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            List<Long> componentIds = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());


            Instant startTest = Instant.now();
            List<AssignmentApplicationBE> wrapperList = componentPABean.findAssignmentApplications(acId, materialNodelist, substanceNodelist, threshold);


            LOG.info("Getting NodeIds from assignments ...");
            List<Long> nodeIds = getAssignmentsNodeIds(wrapperList);
            LOG.info("NodeIds size is [" + nodeIds.size() + "]");
            Map<Long, Long> nodeIdMap = nodePABean.findNodeIdsMapByNodeIds(nodeIds);
            LOG.info("NodeIdMap is ready");


            LOG.info("Start of ParseEachAssignmentApplication [" + startTest.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND) + "]");

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

            for (int i = 0; i < wrapperList.size(); i += BATCH_SIZE) {
                LOG.info("Batching number [" + i + "]");

                List<AssignmentApplicationBE> batch = wrapperList.subList(i, Math.min(i + BATCH_SIZE, wrapperList.size()));

                List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
                for (AssignmentApplicationBE each : batch) {
                    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
                                    parseEachAssignmentApplication(each, componentIds, notRelevantModules, relevantModules,nodeIdMap),
                            executor
                    );
                    futures.add(future);
                }
                CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
            }
            executor.shutdown();
```

and

```
private void parseEachAssignmentApplication(AssignmentApplicationBE assignmentApplicationBE, List<Long> componentIds,
                                                Map<Long, List<Long>> notRelevantModules, Map<Long, List<Long>> relevantModules, Map<Long, Long> nodeIdMap) {
        Long nodeId = assignmentApplicationBE.getNodeId();
        List<OemAppcodeBE> appcodes = assignmentApplicationBE.getOemAppcodes();
        if (nodeId == null) {
            return;
        }
        componentIds.add(nodeId);

        long componentNodeId = nodeIdMap.get(nodeId);
```

```
    long componentNodeId = nodeIdMap.get(nodeId);
```

is this safe action to do?

I've tried with unmodifable map and it worked so i guess it is safe to use if it is just reading ,but not sure ?
I'm just worried about this result because a ot of threads run concurrently.

Comment: Does anything modify `nodeIdMap` concurrently? If no, then it's safe, if yes, then it's not safe. You may want to make an immutable copy (`Map.copyOf(..)`) so you can be sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel nothing modifies it ,but componentNodeId this is is used to search in db

Comment: Why not leave it as it is, with `ConcurrentHashMap()`? Then you don't have to think about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421 ya solution just then would have to take care of nulls

Comment: well okay thanks a lot guys,then i'll leave it as it is since just reading

Comment: The proper way to notify people in comments is to use @username

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okay will keep in mind,Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe to read from and variable from multiple threads of the content is constant (not modified).

The reason that non constant values needs special treatment is that the CPU cannot cache values from the memory. Worst case, values must be read from memory (~ x10-x100 times slower than reading from CPU register or cache) each time they are used since they may have been updated by another thread since last time the current thread accessed them. (JVM experts may have more input here, maybe some kind of dirty flag is used to optimize things. Point is that it at least brings some extra work.)

Telling the JVM to synchronise (by using a concurrent hash map) is not only unnecessary in this case, but comes with a performance cost.

Comment: What is JWM? Did you mean JVM?

Comment: A more important reason is that a non-concurrent data structure may have moments during which it is incoherent during update.

Comment: @user207421 it's not really incoherent in memory, it's the mentioned caches that are not updated, making the data look incoherent.